# full interface translation with wysiwyg editor

Tags: php, user-interface, wysiwyg, multilingual

i need to provide the site administrator with a way to translate the site interface. all the text in the buttons and titles and labels should be editable, and when a new  language is added he will be able to enter a new translation for them.

for that purpose i want to use a wysiwyg editor. i have some experience with thous editors so i have no technical problems making it work. my problem is this :

when i edit html with wysiwyg editor i then submit the changes to server via ajax request for storage (in a db). in order to identify the content that is submitted, and relate it to a certain table/row, i use a unique identifier, for example `table_name+row_id`. this identifier is written in to the html and then used when submitting the content

when the content is originated in the db and have `table_name+row_id` there is no problem, but how can i edit the interface, all the static html elements that don't have this uid.

first of all i moved all the static text to the db, but the problem is that all this content is originated in the html file so i don't have any way to id it and tie it to the db row that needs to be edited

now i use hand written unique ids in the html, but this require to much time and effort. **i need a better way to do this**, and i was not able to find anything online

here is how it works now:

html file :

```
<h1 id="page_title">
  <?=get_text('51920ae518647','This is a page title')?>
</h1>
```

*the `$uniq_id` parameter is hand written in the html

server side :

```
function get_text($uniq_id, $default){
        $return_text = "";
    if (!empty($page['data']['html_text']['by_uniq_id'][$uniq_id])){
            $return_text = $page['data']['html_text']['by_uniq_id'][$uniq_id]->text;
    }
    else{// insert the default value to the db
        $text = new html_text($uniq_id, $default);
        if ($text->save()){
            $page['data']['html_text']['by_uniq_id'][$uniq_id] = $text;
            $return_text = $default;
        }
        else{
            error_log("Get html text error : new text save failed");
        }
    }
    if ($is_admin)
        return '<span class="editable_content" id="' . $uniq_id . '">' . $return_text . '</span>';
else
        return $return_text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example in PHP with .PO files (also used in other languages) they use the text itself as the key. In your example, the key would be:

```
This is a page title
```

Even if you have this string twice on your website, it would not matter, since the translation is always the same. Of course, sometimes individual words have different meanings, but you could just add the page name to the key.

Comment: its a good idea. is it better if i make a hash of a text and use it as a key?

Comment: A hash is very unreadable. I'm just saying how PHP is doing it. Can't be all that wrong.